# local variable 'logger' referenced before assignment?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ubuntu, openni2, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using fresh install ROS indigo with Ubuntu 14.04
When trying to start openni2_launch I get below error.
What could be wrong?

```
ros@host1:~$ roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch
[openni2.launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni2_launch] nor is [openni2_launch] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
Traceback (most recent call last):openni2_launch
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch", line 35, in <module>
    roslaunch.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 292, in main
    logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logger' referenced before assignment
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190389/local-variable-%27logger%27-referenced-before-assignment?/) by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch is complaining that it can't find the openni2_launch package. Do you have it installed?

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni2-launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on 2014-08-16**:
No :-) THX That solved the issue.